# While Loop Compare

Tags: java

Got problem when using while loop, it says illegal starts of operation

```
   int monthInput;
        System.out.println("Prefered Month :  (1-12)");
        monthInput = promptUser.nextInt();
        while((monthInput <= 31) && (monthInput => 1)){
            monthInput = promptUser.nextInt();

        }
        Month dateMonth = Month.of(monthInput);
        System.out.println(dateMonth);


}
```

Comment: what is that means => ??? you mean to say greater than equal if yes then >=  should be the way to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop condition, you wrote

```
monthInput => 1
```

This is wrong - there is no operator `=>` in Java.
You probably meant

```
monthInput >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `monthInput => 1` condition to `monthInput >= 1`

```
int monthInput;
System.out.println("Prefered Month :  (1-12)");
monthInput = promptUser.nextInt();
while((monthInput <= 31) && (monthInput => 1)){
   monthInput = promptUser.nextInt();
}
 Month dateMonth = Month.of(monthInput);
 System.out.println(dateMonth);
}
```